# Array only adds single entry to Struct after for-loop despite containing more entries - Swift/Xcode

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

Im running a `for loop` to create a filtered array of results that match an array of downloaded files. The output `let items` contains everything i want but i can not seem to get it to map across a struct properly. If i `print(items)` it shows all the results but if I `print(self.podepisodes)` after `self.podepisodes = items` it only shows 1 entry.

More code below for context:

```
struct Episodes: Codable {
    let show: String
    let showHost: String
    let showDescription: String
    let showArtURL: String
    let epNumber: String
    let epTitle: String
    let epAudioURL: String
    let epArtURL: String
    let epLength: String
    let epDescription: String
    let releaseDate: String
    let date: String
    let exclusive: String
    let subscriptionAudio1: String
    let youtubeURL: String
}

 var podepisodes: [Episodes]?

//have omitted some code here in the interest of not posting a huge page load. Can edit and add it if anyone would like. 

    let JSONData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Episodes].self, from: data)

     DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    guard let trueLocation = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {return }
                    let filePath = trueLocation.path

   let fileList:  Array = try! self.fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: filePath)

                    for file in fileList {
                       let items = JSONData.filter { (item: Episodes) -> Bool in
                        return URL(string: item.epAudioURL)?.lastPathComponent == file

                    }

                        self.podepisodes = items
                      print(items)
                         }

                    print(self.podepisodes)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must append items to the array, now you are overwriting the content of `self.podepisodes` each time in the loop. So replace `self.podepisodes = items` with

```
self.podepisodes.append(contentsOf: items)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i was pulling my hair out! I had been trying with ```.append``` earlier but in the wrong place. Thanks again.