# Swift only stores last item in Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

I want to retrieve some data using firebase and store it in an empty array. Afterwards I have to store it in a global array (yes I know I shouldn't do that).
But the array only stores the last variable. I can assume that it is because the way firebase is retrieving the data in this function.
But i would like to have all the values appended to the Array.

Maybe someone can help me :)

```
static func jobs(for user: User, completion: @escaping ([TeamMember]) -> Void) {
     let ref = Database.database().reference().child("team").child(user.uid)
        
        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for case let child as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                
                guard let dict = child.value as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("Error")
                    return completion([])
                }
                
                
                
                
                let memberJob = dict["memberJob"] as! String
                print("memberJob: \(memberJob)")
                
                var memberJobs: [String] = []
                memberJobs.append(memberJob)
                
                for job in memberJobs {
                    print("New Job incoming: ", job)
                }
                
                globalJobs = memberJobs

            }        
    })
        
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array only adds single entry to Struct after for-loop despite containing more entries - Swift/Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374438/array-only-adds-single-entry-to-struct-after-for-loop-despite-containing-more-en)

Comment: Why do you want to retreive the data and store it in an empty array and then later store it in a global array? Why don't you just store it in the global array to start with. Also, what is a 'global array' in this use case? Also, you've specified a completion handler but you're not doing anything with it, other than returning an empty array if the child.value is nil? There are several good answers but without understanding what you're trying to do it's guesswork (albeit *good* guesswork). So maybe if you can clue us in a bit we can provide a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new array every loop with `var memberJobs: [String] = []`

```
 var memberJobs: [String] = []
 memberJobs.append(memberJob)
```

Move this line out

```
var memberJobs: [String] = []
```

---

```
static func jobs(for user: User, completion: @escaping ([TeamMember]) -> Void) {
     let ref = Database.database().reference().child("team").child(user.uid)
        
       var memberJobs: [String] = []  /// hererererre 

        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for case let child as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                
                guard let dict = child.value as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("Error")
                    return completion([])
                }  

                let memberJob = dict["memberJob"] as! String
                print("memberJob: \(memberJob)")
                
                memberJobs.append(memberJob)
                
                for job in memberJobs {
                    print("New Job incoming: ", job)
                }

            }    
                
            globalJobs = memberJobs    
    })
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new empty array in each iteration of the loop.

Create it once **before** the loop and assign the array to `globalJobs` **after** the loop

```
static func jobs(for user: User, completion: @escaping ([TeamMember]) -> Void) {
     let ref = Database.database().reference().child("team").child(user.uid)
        
        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var memberJobs: [String] = []
            for case let child as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                
                guard let dict = child.value as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("Error")
                    return completion([])
                }
                let memberJob = dict["memberJob"] as! String
                print("memberJob: \(memberJob)")
                
                
                memberJobs.append(memberJob)
            }
                
            for job in memberJobs {
                print("New Job incoming: ", job)
            }
                
            globalJobs = memberJobs         
    })
        
}
```

And the completion handler makes no sense if you call it only on failure.

Answer (score 1):

This line is looping over each child in the snapshot

```
for case let child as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
```

inside that loop you create `var memberJobs: [String] = []` which is an empty array. Then you add a member job so it has one item. You then assign this 1 item array to `globalJobs = memberJobs` so they are exactly the same. This assignment occurs over and over again for the loop `for case let child as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children` that is why you are only left with 1 item at then end.

You should declare `var memberJobs: [String] = []` before the snapshot loop and assign `globalJobs = memberJobs` after the snapshot loop is done.